# wenzhixin bootstrap-table detailView (child row) not initializing

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using the wenzhixin bootstrap table and I am trying to get another bootstrap table to initialize in the child row which is referred to in the code as 'detailView'.

I was using datatables but this, so far, seems simpler and more straight forward to work with.

I will be passing the key from the parent row to the child row. Right now I am just using a static table that I got to initialize outside of the child row, now I am simply moving it to the child row, trying to get it to initialize, and then I will make the content dynamic.

The data is passing, but it does not seem the table is initializing. I'm wondering if I need to hide a table somewhere that I can initialize behind the scenes and then pass the content to the row (seems messy, but I can't think of another way to pull this off).

my code to initalize the detailView in the main table;

```
detailView: true,
detailFormatter: 'compExtInfo',
```

here is what I am returning to the child row (detailView)

```
function compExtInfo(index, row) {
    var pAPI = row.api;

    var hOut = '<table data-toggle="table" data-url="./completion/getcompletionext.php?api=49-037-28606">'+
            '<thead>'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<th data-field="api" data-visible=false>API</th>'+
                    '<th data-field="finalfieldreport">Last Fld Rp</th>'+
                    '<th data-field="onbase">OnBase</th>'+
                    '<th data-field="tbg">Tbg</th>'+
                    '<th data-field="active">Actv</th>'+
                '</tr>'+
            '</thead>'+
        '</table>';
        console.log(hOut);
    return hOut;
}
```

here is the table / grid that will fully initialize if placed alone outside of a child table (same code as above, literally copied and pasted into the function).

```
        <table data-toggle="table" data-url="./completion/getcompletionext.php?api=49-037-28606">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="api" data-visible=false>API</th>
                    <th data-field="finalfieldreport">Last Fld Rp</th>
                    <th data-field="onbase">OnBase</th>
                    <th data-field="tbg">Tbg</th>
                    <th data-field="active">Actv</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this finally, code is listed below.

Main table initializations for the child row listed below;

```
detailView: true,    
onExpandRow: function (index, row, $detail) {
            compExtInfo($detail, row);}
```

Function called from the main table; get row key and pass to table builder

```
function compExtInfo($detail, row) {
    pAPI = row.api;

    buildTable($detail.html('<table></table>').find('table'), pAPI);
}
```

Table builder function

```
function buildTable($ext, api) {

    $ext.bootstrapTable({
        url: './completion/getcompletionext.php?api='+api,
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'api',
                visible: false,
                title: 'API'
            },{
                field: 'finalfieldreport',
                title: 'Last Fld Rp'
            ...
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On event from main table

```js
table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function (e, index, row, $detail) {
          
   var tableD = $detail.append('<table id="table_' + row["impresora"] + '"></table>').find('table');

            tableD.bootstrapTable({
                editable: true,
                showHeader: false,
                idField: 'ip',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: "json",
                url: baseUrl + 'app_modules/Cups/classes/admin_impresoras.php?accion=get&impresora=' + row['impresora'],
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: 'IMPRESORA',
                        field: 'impresora',
                        halign: 'left',
                        valign: 'middle',
                        visible: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'IP',
                        field: 'ip',
                        halign: 'left',
                        valign: 'middle',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: {
                            type: 'text',
                            url: baseUrl + 'app_modules/Cups/classes/admin_impresoras.php?accion=updateip&impresora=' + row['impresora'],
                            ajaxOptions: {
                                type: 'POST'//,                    
                            }
                            , success: function (text) {
                                if (text === "success") {

                                } else
                                    alert(text);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'PREDETERMINADA',
                        field: 'sw_predeterminada',
                        halign: 'left',
                        valign: 'middle',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: {
                            type: 'text',
                            url: baseUrl + 'app_modules/Cups/classes/admin_impresoras.php?accion=updateip&impresora=' + row['impresora'],
                            ajaxOptions: {
                                type: 'POST'//,                    
                            }
                            , success: function (text) {
                                if (text === "success") {

                                } else
                                    alert(text);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                ]
            });



        });
```